# Use Vuex to connect many new Vue

Tags: vue.js

I've been working on a project in Asp.net for a few months and trying to slowly replace the frontend from razor to Vue. Currently, I have an issue where I want to communicate between a page and a partial component. They are in separate files so it seems like my best option to speak to them is through Vuex. I've only used Vuex a couple of times but really like what it does.

My problem is that every page I've created in the current application is broken into its own new Vue instead of encompassing the app into one Vue application (This was done because I was slowly moving from razor to Vue, I hope to eventually embody everything in one Vue frontend)

Is there any way for me to call Vuex between two separate Vue micro-applications?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/store.js"></script>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#appOne',
  methods: {
    increment () {
      store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement () {
        store.commit('decrement')
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Above is the initial app where the Vuex event will be triggered. And then in the component below the change will render in the frontend.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/store.js"></script>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#appTwo',
    computed: {
      count () {
        return store.state.count
      }
    },
  })
</script>
```

Below is the basic Vuex store that would be implemented between these two components. I have both Vue and Vuex being imported into my apps headers.

```
### store.js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
})
```

I tried this method above but it isn't working, can someone explain to me what I'm missing or if this is possible?

Comment: Fixed syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the `store` to each Vue instance:

```js
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#appOne',
    store,             // added this line
    methods: {
```

And:

```js
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#appTwo',
    store,             // added this line
    computed: {
```

Note: you also had a syntax problem at the end of your instance declarations: `)} </script>` should be `}) </script>`.

Demo:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#appOne',
  store,
  methods: {
    increment () {
      store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement () {
        store.commit('decrement')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#appTwo',
  computed: {
    count () {
      return store.state.count
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="appOne">
  <p>appOne: {{ $store.state.count }}</p>
  <button @click="increment">increment</button>
  <button @click="decrement">decrement</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="appTwo">
  <p>appTwo: {{ count }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, but it still isn't working on my end. I think the bigger issue is I have the components in different files so I need to import the Store into each file. I tried to `export default store` and `import store from '~/scripts/store.js'` but I think I'd need webpack for that and my project isn't setup for it :(

Comment: Actually, you don't. Your files, as you described in the question, should work (`script` tags and all). Do `console.log('store is', store)` before the `new Vue({ ...` part to test if there is a `store` object available.

Comment: Check out this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/fXYCME0sorkhbuMDi6vg?p=preview multiple files, see?

Comment: Ahh thanks so much. I realized part of the issue was I was using @click syntax that breaks razor... I'm not a big fan of Asp.net but I'm glad I got this working. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I think it's valuable to include "Do console.log('store is', store) before the new Vue({ ... part to test if there is a store object available" in the answer as an additional warning, just stumbled by here wandering and got interested, nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you have your components in separate files, so it seems that you have separate applications in separate pages. The `vuex` store doesn't perform any "magic" under the hood, it doesn't automatically persist/reload the state, and when the browser loads a new page, the old javascript context is lost. `vuex` is designed to work in the context of a SPA application.

If you want to make it work across multiple pages, you have to explicitly persist and reload your `vuex` store, for example using a remote API or localStorage.

LocalStorage would lend itself well in the case of your simple example. You can do it yourself or use a vuex plugin like [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate), [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist), [vuex-localstorage](https://github.com/crossjs/vuex-localstorage).
For example, using vuex-persistedstate:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

(and remember to add the store to your Vue instances)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to use Vuex to communicate between partials on the same page. I'm not concerned with application state being saved on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

I had some weird problems with a page were there was one single store and many vue instances, some instances had computed methods (with store state) that weren't being updated.

I passed the last 8 hours trying to figure out what was the problem, I stripped the project of all major dependencies and still nothing.

Turns out the app was being build with `rollup` and was including all the dependencies (including Vue/Vuex). So every one of my resulting js had a copy of the Vue/Vuex methods.

If you think you've exhausted all your options you don't lose anything making sure that the resulting javascript of a simple hello world is in the range of 2-5KB (using external vue dependencies) and not 50-70KB (in my case).

I had to put this answer here hoping I can help someone.